# Undefined symbol sunOglCurPrimTablePtr in Solaris-x86

Tags: opengl, x86, solaris, solaris-10

I was porting a C++ program from Solaris Sparc to Solaris x86. The program utilizes OpenGL library and the compilation is performed in a [Sun Ultra27 workstation](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/desktop-workstations/028393.htm) with the default GCC (3.4.3) and OpenGL library come with the machine.

However, the following OpenGL call couldn't found while linking:

```
Undefined symbol                    first referenced in file
sunOglCurPrimTablePtr               ../../lib/libgltt.so
sunOglCurrentContext                ../../lib/libgltt.so
```

which, both sunOglCurPrimTablePtr and sunOglCurrentContext should be available in the default OpenGL library /usr/lib/libGL.so (links to /usr/X11/lib/NVIDIA/libGL.so.1). But I couldn't find anything from it:

```
> nm /usr/lib/libGL.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so:
```

Searching on web, SUN or Nvidia didn't lead to any helpful resource. Any clue or helps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that certain standard OpenGL API would be translated into SUN's internal functions. By defining SUN_OGL_NO_VERTEX_MACRO compilation flag, the program wouldn't refer to sunOgl* symbol anymore and the issue resolved.

The information is found at http://java423.vicp.net:8652/infoserver.central/data/syshbk/collections/TECHNICALINSTRUCTION/1-61-210284-1.html, item 9:

> Without the SUN_OGL_NO_VERTEX_MACRO
>   compilation flag, all calls to
>   glVertex*(), glNormal*(), glColor*(),
>   glIndex*() and glTexCoord*() will be
>   translated into internal,
>   performance-enhanced routines. These
>   function calls will NOT show up when
>   dbx() is used, or when performing
>   SLI-related interposing of OpenGL for
>   Solaris applications.

The OpenGL libraries came with SUN Solaris Sparc contains SUN internal routines. But they are not existed in the OpenGL libraris in Solaris x86/x64 (which is provided by NVIDIA). I am not sure where exactly is the "translation" occurred, but our issue resolved! :)